# Terminate endless running process in a batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am trying to find a way to automate a process with a batch file.

The process is one that logs output to a file indefinitely until it gets a break (ctrl+c) command via the keyboard.

I can't seem to find a way to get it to respond to a break as the process itself seems to tie up the command window until the interrupt is presented.

Effectively I want to run this command for 24 hours (or as close to as possible), cancel it, do some file moving/renaming and then start the command off again.

So far I have:

```
e:
md e:\aculogs
cd e:\aculogs
del 14daysago00.txt
ren 13daysago00.txt 14daysago00.txt
ren 12daysago00.txt 13daysago00.txt
ren 11daysago00.txt 12daysago00.txt
ren 10daysago00.txt 11daysago00.txt
ren 9daysago00.txt 10daysago00.txt
ren 8daysago00.txt 9daysago00.txt
ren 7daysago00.txt 8daysago00.txt
ren 6daysago00.txt 7daysago00.txt
ren 5daysago00.txt 6daysago00.txt
ren 4daysago00.txt 5daysago00.txt
ren 3daysago00.txt 4daysago00.txt
ren 2daysago00.txt 3daysago00.txt
ren yesterday00.txt 2daysago00.txt
copy e:\Port00.txt D:\aculogs\yesterday00.txt
del e:\Port00.txt

cd %PROGRAMFILES%\aculab\v6\bin
v6trace -port 188746 0 -trace_high > e:\Port00.txt
```

I need to end that last command after as close to 24 hours as possible, so that I can get task scheduler to kick it off again straight after.
Am I reaching beyond the limits of what I can do in batch files?
I'm a noob to all of this...

Comment: If it's being launched by the Task Scheduler, why not use the "stop the task if it runs longer than..." option?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to have the following at line 1:

```
taskkill /im v6trace.exe /f
```

This will kill the v6trace application.  You can then schedule this through windows task manager to execute everyday at midnight.

The first thing it would do is kill v6trace (the last running command in the last run) - effectively ending your previous batch, and then start the while process again.

Hope this helps,